# Why electric potential is separable?

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, potential, voltage, gauss-law

In Electrostatics, if we consider a region without charges the electrostatic potential $V$ obeys Laplace's Equation $\nabla^2 V = 0$. We can tackle this with separation of variables. In cartesian coordinates we have $V(x,y,z) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$

I want to know why $V$ is separable function
$$V = \frac{kq}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}.$$

I can't find a way to separate variable in terms of x y and z can someone give me explanation on why it makes sense

Comment: Look at other coordinate systems…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the solution to Laplace's equation will not be separable, *i.e.,* it will not be possible to find $X, Y, Z$ such that $V(x, y, z) = X(x) Y(y) Z(z)$. And that's where the great difficulty arises in finding closed form solutions to partial differential equations. Sometimes we get lucky and the PDE is separable in a different coordinate system, but in the general case it will not be separable.

However, if we only need a numerical solution, then we can try to express $V$ as a (usually infinite) sum of separable solutions:

\begin{equation}
V(x, y, z) = \sum_{i, j, k} a_{ijk} X_i(x) Y_j(y) Z_k(z)
\end{equation}

Here, each $X_i(x) Y_j(y) Z_k(z)$ individually satisfies Laplace's equation, and if you do the algebra, together with boundary conditions, you find that there are only a countably finite number of possible $X$ functions, indexed in some obvious way by a natural number $i$, and likewise with $Y$ and $j$, $Z$ and $k$. And furthermore, for physically realistic solutions, we can assume that the coefficients $a_{ijk}$ fall sufficiently quickly with increasing $i, j, k$ that we can truncate the summation at some reasonable point to get a solution that is sufficiently accurate for our needs.

I'm sure there are people on this site who could explain to you the mathematical theory behind why this works for certain types of PDEs and what additional conditions need to be imposed, but I couldn't even begin to do that. I think it does work in practice with physically realistic solutions to Laplace's equation, and so physicists do it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a function being separable is a coordinate-dependent statement and we can even use your specific function to exemplify. The function $V(x,y,z)$ in Cartesian coordinates is $$V(x,y,z)=\dfrac{kq}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\tag{1}$$

which is clearly not separable. But if you change coordinates to spherical coordinates by means of the definition $$x=r\cos\phi\sin\theta,\quad y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta,\quad z=r\cos\theta\tag{2},$$

then the corresponding function assumes the simple form $$V(r,\theta,\phi)=\dfrac{kq}{r}\tag{3}$$
which is trivially separable since it depends on a single coordinate.

Finally, let me mention one important point about the method of separation of variables for solving PDEs. The idea is not that any solution to the PDE will be separable, since that is clearly not true. The idea is that using separation of variables will provide you with a *basis of solutions*, and that the basis functions are separable.